# Image Comparison using OpenCV in order to determine traffic density

Tags: image, opencv

I am working on a project which gives plots real time traffic status on Google Maps, & make it available to user on an Android phone and web browser. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcAyMngkzjk

I need to compare 2 images in openCV in order to determine traffic density. Can you please guide me how to compare the images? Should I go for histogram comparison or simple image subtraction?

Comment: What I can tell you is that what you want to do is illegal - steal traffic information from Google and show it in your mobile app. Google Maps for Android is a legitimate source of traffic for drivers.

Answer (score 3):

One common solution is using background subtraction to track moving objects (cars) and then export an image with the moving objects remarked, so you can easily extract the objects from the image. If this is not the case, you will have to detect the vehicles and that's more challenging task because as carlosdc says there are many approaches depending on the angle of the camera, the size of vehicles, light conditions, cluttered backgrounds, etc.
If you specify a little more the problem ...

Answer (score 2):

It really depends, and it would be impossible to determine without looking at your images.

Also, let me point out that it may be quite difficult to make this work adequately in all conditions: day/night, ray/shine, etc. Perhaps you should start by looking at what others have done and how good/bad it works. One such example would be [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~saket/pubs/dmsn2007.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

try to read this two tutorials about OpenCV versus detect/recognition and find contur.

http://python-catalin.blogspot.ro/search/label/OpenCV

or try to find the color change in your image ... ( for example find colors versus background street )